# Can you cross validate a regression model using supervised learning?

Tags: r, validation, stata, roc

Our team created a regression model based on a select data size/parameter and achieved a good C-statistic (area under ROC curve).

We faced a few difficulties with submission for publication, so I added a machine learning component to support our model. The model was trained using the same data size/parameters split randomly, kind of like K-fold cross validation and the idea is to show that a supervised learning model using the same parameters achieves a worse/equal C-statistic as our original model.

My question is, is this a legitimate way to support our regression model? I had never seen someone use machine learning to support a regression model. Furthermore, can I say the supervised learning cross validate/validate the regression, or should I use more general wording (support/ strengthen) to avoid confusion?

Comment: Can you please clarify why you don’t consider the regression model as a machine learning, supervised model as well? About the wording I agree on the confusion, “supports” or “confirms” the hypothesis sound better to me.

Comment: I may be wrong if this is used somewhere, but to cross-validate a model does not mean to confirm its good performance. To cross-validate a model simply means to score it against many train/test combinations.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you did the cross-validation. You claim that the model was trained with the randomly selected samples. But at the same time, you said you were using the same parameters from linear regression with AUC.

Comment: @RodrigoNader: Sorry for the confusion, the regression model was built using a weighed index of 21 predictive factors like bmi, creatine_level, etc...    So it essentially just a algebraic equation

Comment: @RodrigoNader: The idea was to validate with machine learning, and the machine learning was internally validated via cross-validate

Comment: @kevin012 Sorry for the confusion, I meant the input data used the same predictive factors (bmi, creatine_level, age, etc...). The data are just split randomly in the different models

Comment: I would recommend using the validation term only for what it is commonly used in Machine Learning, which is scoring a model in order to decide if it’s going to be used or not. About the “regression model”, I understand that it wasn’t trained, So it’s not an actual regression, it is just a rule-based model based on weights set manually, is that correct?